# Polling the server in background

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am busy developing a Firefox extension and I have a Widget that opens a Panel. How do I have a background script that is constantly running/polling the server to fetch updates. These updates would then need to be injected into the DOM of the Panel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of your extension scripts are "background scripts". What you are asking about seems to be a way to poll the server regularly - you use the [`timers` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/addon-kit/docs/timers.html) for that, method `setInterval()`. The callback would than use the [`request` module](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/packages/addon-kit/docs/request.html) to send a request to the server.

As to communicating information to a widget/panel - you use [the usual approach](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.5/dev-guide/addon-development/content-scripts/using-postmessage.html) to send messages to the content scripts running there.

Comment: Thanks again Wladimir, your help is much appreciated!